HAVING and LIKE not highlighted in blue but working correctly
In MySQL Workbench, I noticed that the HAVING and LIKE statements are not highlighted in blue in the editor, unlike other keywords. However, they function correctly when executing queries.
Why is this happening, and how can I fix the syntax highlighting for these keywords?

I downloaded and tried various code_editor.xml files from the internet, but there was no solution.
There was no change.
